# Get the real FPS from MediaCapture

Tags: c#, video, uwp

I have an application (UWP) that uses the MediaCapture library for
see and record the stream of my webcam. But I would like to be able to read in real time the FPS of what I display. I searched the documentation but found nothing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I would like to be able to read in real time the FPS of what I display.

Currently, UWP does not provide real time FPS when video recroding. But you could get video frame rate from [`VideoEncodingProperties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.mediaproperties.videoencodingproperties).

```
public uint FrameRate(VideoEncodingProperties properties)
{
    get
    {
        if (properties is VideoEncodingProperties)
        {
            if ((properties as VideoEncodingProperties).FrameRate.Denominator != 0)
            {
                return (properties as VideoEncodingProperties).FrameRate.Numerator /
                    (properties as VideoEncodingProperties).FrameRate.Denominator;
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```